# Qt Quick application locks up when 25 application windows are created

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qml, qt5

I'm experiencing a problem where my Qt quick application will lock up after opening 25 ApplicationWindows. I have no idea why so I wrote this simple test app to reproduce the issue. It begins by creating a window with a button and clicking this button creates another window. The window it creates has a button to spawn another window with a button, this will happen infinitely. However, the application locks up after I hit exactly 24 sub menus ( 25 total including the first window created initially). No crash, no error, just stops responding to mouse clicks. Memory and other resources appear to be ok. So why are we locking up? Does Qt have a limit on the number of application windows that can be open? Iv never heard of one. Am I breaking a limit in Windows where a program can only spawn so many windows? I highly doubt that's the case. I have been researching this for a while now with no good reason why it locks up. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

## Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "MenuManager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute( Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES );
   QApplication app( argc, argv );
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   MenuManager* menuManager = new MenuManager( &engine );
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "menuManager", menuManager );
   engine.load( QUrl(QStringLiteral( "qrc:/main.qml" ) ) );

   if ( engine.rootObjects().isEmpty() )
      return -1;

   return app.exec();

   delete menuManager;
}
```

## MenuManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>

class MenuManager :
   public QObject
{
   public:
      explicit MenuManager( QQmlApplicationEngine* engine );

   public slots:
      void openSubMenu();

   private:
      Q_OBJECT

      QQmlApplicationEngine* engine;
};
```

## MenuManager.cpp

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QWindow>

#include "MenuManager.h"

MenuManager::MenuManager( QQmlApplicationEngine* engine ) :
   engine{ engine }
{
}

void MenuManager::openSubMenu()
{
   QWindow* createdComponent = nullptr;
   QQmlComponent component( engine, QUrl( QString( "qrc:///Menu.qml" ) ), 
                            QQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous );

   if ( component.status() == QQmlComponent::Ready )
      createdComponent = qobject_cast< QWindow* >( component.create() );
}
```

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{
   id: mainWindow

   title: qsTr( "Test" )

   visible: true
   x: 100
   y: 100
   width: 200
   height: 200

   Button
   {
      text: "TopLevelMenu"

      onClicked: menuManager.openSubMenu();
   }
}
```

## Menu.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
   id: menu

   visible: true
   x: 100
   y: 100
   width: 200
   height: 200

   Button
   {
      onClicked: menuManager.openSubMenu()

      text: "SubMenu"
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your OS, version of Qt and the features of the PC where you tried ?, I've tested in Linux with many more windows than you point out and I have not had problems.

Comment: Windows 7, Qt Quick version 5.9.5. Thank you for testing on a Linux system. Leads me to believe it is a Windows constraint.

Comment: It would be great to try other versions of windows because it seems that the problem is only windows.

Comment: I agree. I have access to a Windows 10 PC that I will try this on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was able to find this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031218-00/?p=41453 It states 50 ist the limit for WinXP, so it seems to actually be a limit of windows. Nothing said regarding Windows 7 however, so either the limit was further reduced, or for whatever reason these windows count as two

Comment: Just out of interest, for what you need 25 windows opened?

Comment: Felix, thank you for your research, I will investigate that as a possible reason. Folibis, when I found this issue, it uncovered a bug in our software where we were hiding windows, but not closing them. The fix was easy, just close the windows when it's time to hide them. However, I'm still curious as to why this limit seems to exist. It may re-introduce itself in future development.